# Calculate MHz from Cycles, Time and Instructions per Second?

Tags: arm, profiling, clock

I have profiled my program which gives me the following information:

```
Execution time in profiler: 17.39 seconds  
Instructions: 498.622.849  
Average Instructions per Sec: 28.656.485  
Cycles: 712.586.889
```

The code is processing a music file with a duration of 10 seconds.

I'm simulating the code on an ARM Cortex M4.

**How can I now calculate from this data, how much MHz the processor needs to run the code?**

Comment: That's like asking how fast you need to drive your car on a 1 mile track without specifying your target lap time. How much computational power you need to complete your workload depends on how quickly you want it done.

Comment: No reason to assume it will be linear...

Comment: what frequency are you running now?  it takes 17 seconds to do 10 seconds worth of data?  so not realtime, what if you double your frequency?